# Reference material for Simulink Autocode generation

Tags: simulink

I'm extremely new to Simulink. I've been trying to get familiar with the C\C++ autocode generation features and am completely confused. I haven't been able to find any good tutorials/videos that lay out what's exactly going on. For playing around I created a new Simulink model with just a gain block. I generate the code and see two folders with code files but have no idea what to do with them. I was expecting a VS solution with files related to the simple gain block, probably just a simple function or something. I'm probably looking at this wrong but if someone could just lay out the process I would be well on my way to understanding what's going on. I come from a CS background and have used MATLAB for projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a good place to start would be the examples at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/rtw/examples/.

However, code generation from Simulink is an advanced topic for experienced users, so for you, it would be a bit like trying to run before learning to walk. I would suggest learning the basics of Simulink first.  If you are a student, MathWorks provide some tutorials at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/academia/student_center/tutorials/. There are plenty of resources on Simulink on the internet.

MathWorks also provide training courses (at a cost): http://www.mathworks.co.uk/services/training/